# OAuth without Asp.net Identity

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

This is a subjective / design level question. I am implementing OAuth JWT authentication / authorization mechanism for my web api. I have my own user store which is held in a sql server database. WebApi template has lots of ASP.NET identity specific classes. Now my question is

1. Is it necessary or good to use asp.net identity with custom oauth Provider? All that i want to do is to issue a JWT.

2.Is it a good idea to inject DbContext directly into OauthProvider instead of using UserManager class which comes with the template ?

3. Should i use IdentityContext or DbContext for my database queries to check user credentials and roles.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this. Did you end up implementing OAuth without ASP.NET Identity?